# How do I catch the swipe type with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have these lines of code in jQuery and I need to catch the name of the swype type in a string.

```
$('.client-content').on('swipeleft swiperight', function(){

        var curActiveClient = $('.clients-belt').find('.active-client'),
            position = $('.clients-belt').children().index(curActiveClient),
            clientNum = $('.client-unit').length;

        if (event === 'swipeleft') {

            //do something

        } else if (event === 'swiperight') {

            //do something else

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you want is to know whether the swipe is left or right...

```
$('.client-content').on('swipe', function(){
   var curActiveClient = $('.clients-belt').find('.active-client'),
      position = $('.clients-belt').children().index(curActiveClient),
      clientNum = $('.client-unit').length;

   $(this).on("swipeleft", function(){
   //some code
   })
   $(this).on("swiperight", function(){
   //some code
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! 
I just needed to change those two "this" in '.client-content' because it didn't work otherwise ;)

Comment: I'm glad it helped :D

Comment: It's one of the first times I try to do something using jQuery and I think I still have to get how it works :D